# How troubleshoot gateway timeout on openshift/OKD

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, okd

I'm new to openshift/OKD environment and I'm trieng to deploy nextcloud app on OKD platform. I have already created container image on docker hub and trying to deploy it using OKD web console.

My quation is, when I tried to download container image from docker hub, getting "Gateway Timedout" error. But I dont have any clue to troubleshoot this at the moment.

Done research for days and I'm still strugling. Any Openshift/OKD expert, please let me know troubleshooting procedure for this case.

Error Screenshot:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to input with a fully qualified domain name such as "docker.io/openshift/hello-openshift"?

Comment: Have you seen events in your namespace? You can get event with `oc get event -n <namespace>`.

Comment: Tried both but no luck. For oc get event <namespace> command saying "No resource found in <namespace_name>"

Comment: I checked connectivity from each node from OKD cluster and able to curl the docker.io without issue. But trying to deploy new image via OKD gui cluster only this gateway timeout occuring. can this be because of openshift/kubernetes SCC rules?

Answer (score 0):

I checked connectivity from each node from OKD cluster and able to curl the docker.io without issue. But trying to deploy new image via OKD gui cluster only this gateway timeout occuring. can this be because of openshift/kubernetes SCC rules?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).